# Can I remove whitespace from all column names with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Multiple column names of a CSV have whitespace in them. I'd like to remove the whitespace from these column names with a single *dplyr* command.

I've tried:

```
mpg %>%
  rename("tr ans" = trans, "mo del" = model) %>%
  rename_if(everything(), contains(" "), str_replace_all(" ", ""))
```

I'd expect to produce the original `mpg` dataframe, with the whitespaces that I inserted in the second line removed, but I get an error:

```
Error: Empty pattern not supported
```

Comment: Try `rename_all` instead of `rename_if`

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I wasn't able to make `rename_all` work by myself but @Ronak helped me the rest of the way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @camille metions you can use `rename_all`

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>%
  rename("tr ans" = trans, "mo del" = model) %>%
  rename_all(~str_replace_all(., "\\s+", ""))
```

Or `rename_at` with `everything()`

```
mpg %>%
  rename("tr ans" = trans, "mo del" = model) %>%
  rename_at(vars(everything()), ~str_replace_all(., "\\s+", ""))
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use `sub`:

```
names(mpg) <- gsub("\\s+", "", names(mpg))
```